# Camera and two canvas objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvas objects: the first is map and the second object only for entities.

```
<div class='layers'>
     <canvas id='map'></canvas>
     <canvas id='entities'></canvas>
</div>
```

I wanna make camera for my game. I have two canvas objects and two context objects. So, I've tried to use `ctx.translate`, but i have two layers because the first layer with map should render once when player comes to the area. And it will take much time to render map again... Entity layer is simple and it is possible to use `translate`. Can i use `translate` to map layer without new render?

Comment: No. `context.translate` only affects newly drawn items -- not existing items.

Comment: @markE ok, I can use loading screen to load tiles and I will have fast access. It will take less time to render map (1000/60 will be fine), but does it normal to render map 60 times per second with game entities? It's my first experience with MMO RPG games, I read a lot, but I've still got a lot of questions.

Comment: Sure. If you're just copying tiles from a spritesheet / image then you can draw hundreds of tiles each 1000/60th loop. Of course you will have game logic which takes up time also.

Comment: @markE Thank you, man! You're the best, it's really helpful!